# Isolate word at start of string or after a whitelisted word at the start of the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to `preg_match()` a specific set of rules which I am trying to do a preg match, they are:

1. All words (only letters and numbers) of the string is split up by `_`
2. The first word can be either `Brand` (case insensitive) or the target word I want to grab.
3. After the target word there may be more words or numbers, I do not want this information.
4. Target word will always have at least 1 letter and may or may not have numbers

Examples

- `Brand_GoPro360` => `GoPro360`
- `brand_My247test` => `My247test`
- `bRanD_Apple_worth_84953` => `Apple`
- `Brand_Xbox1_isawesome745` => `Xbox1`
- `Microsoft` => `Microsoft`
- `Office365` => `Office365`
- `KFC_2345_growth` => `KFC`
- `Playstation_iscool3424` => `Playstation`

I have no idea how to start

```
$list = ['Brand_GoPro360', 'brand_My247test', 'bRanD_Apple_worth_84953', 'Brand_Xbox1_isawesome745', 'Microsoft', 'KFC_2345_growth', 'Playstation_iscool3424'];

$pattern = "/(?i)(brand)/";
    foreach ($list as $words) {

        echo (preg_match($pattern, $words));
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want to `echo` these values? or do you want to update `$list` with the replaced strings?  Are all of the input strings always valid?  Is this purely about sanitizing the strings (not checking them for non-alphanumeric characters)?

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry no. Barmar has answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regexp

```
/^(?:brand_)?([a-z0-9]+)/i
```

`(?:brand_)?` makes `brand_` optional at the beginning. `([a-z0-9]+)` matches the next word, and puts it in capture group 1.

```
$pattern = '/^(?:brand_)?([a-z0-9]+)/i';
foreach ($list as $words) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $words, $match)) {
        echo $match[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the error `Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8`

Comment: The last `/` was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Optionally match the leading `brand_` substring (case-insensitively), then capture the next occurring "word" substring, then match any remaining characters in the string.  Replace the full string with the captured substring and your are done.

I am using `[^_]+` to match one or more non-underscore characters, but you can use `[a-z\d]+` to explicitly capture alphanumeric characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7qnNH))

```
var_export(preg_replace('~^(?:brand_)?([^_]+).*~i', '$1', $list));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'GoPro360',
  1 => 'My247test',
  2 => 'Apple',
  3 => 'Xbox1',
  4 => 'Microsoft',
  5 => 'KFC',
  6 => 'Playstation',
)
```